# Can't load CSS in Laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel

Hi I am currently learning Laravel and seem to be having issues loading custom CSS that is located in the public/css/bootstrap.css.

I have been attempting to load it via

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

But it is if the CSS is not getting picked up. When I view the page source (http://portfollo.co.uk/css/bootstrap.css) I just get an error. Any ideas ?

Comment: Does the file `public/css/bootstrap.css` definitely exist?

Comment: Yep it exists, does it need to be inside the app folder by any chance? I just did a direct install through my web server and haven't changed any structures

Comment: Have you modified the `.htaccess` file at all? That file makes sure files that exist in the `public` directory are checked before being passed through the front controller.

Comment: Nope I have not touched that file

Comment: Are you using Laravel 5? It shouldn't be inside the app folder, it should be just `PROJECT_ROOT/public/css/bootstrap.css`

Comment: @Jonathon Yes that's the way its setup. I've tried multiple ways to load but it does not seem to link up.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Try adding '/' before css, like this:  <link href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

Comment: @Marco I don't get any error. When I go to source and click the link to the CSS it throws an error but other than that it does not appear on the page

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143 This is the error when trying to access the CSS ? The only error shown.

Comment: Quick question......does a route need to be setup for the CSS in routes.php? Completely new to this

Comment: I have a feeling that you might have a wildcard route in your `routes.php` file if that's the error you're getting. It's as if Laravel is trying to process it where it should just be directly loaded from the server as a resource. Can you post your `routes.php` file?

Comment: @Jonathon This is the routes.php,  '<?php



Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('home', function () {
    return view('home');
});


?>'

Comment: Thanks, that looks fine. Can you post your `.htaccess` file too?

Comment: @Jonathon Yeah I've been following Lynda and have not changed anything except the home view: Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a website located at the link you gave in your question. All I see is an Apache test page (http://portfollo.co.uk/). You have deployed everything, right? Or is the problem in a local development environment? It might be helpful if you could provide a screenshot of what you're seeing (Full browser window so we can see the URL too)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `public/css/bootstrap.css`

```
 <link href="{{ asset('public/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

OR

```
<link href="'/css/bootstrap.css'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your css file inside public folder, (app/public):
then in your head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('/') }}/style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Public folder will contain all css and js files, you can also create assets folder inside public folder and then point to correct path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('/') }}/assets/css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either, I am starting to think there has something gone wrong with the install

Answer (score 0):

change name as `public/css/bootstrap.css` and put css in that folder. and give the same path.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a **CSS** error. its Routing error. check your **route.php** file just check your source code like this [view-source:http://portfollo.co.uk/css/bootstrap.css](http://view-source:http://portfollo.co.uk/css/bootstrap.css)

you are trying something wrong ??